# Input transient voltage of a regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, switching-regulator, transient

I am using a regulator in a design.  The regulator gives 5V output with 9V to 60V input.

The datasheet says that the input transient voltage is 80V/second.

Does this mean the regulator can handle an 80V transient for 1 second?

Data sheet:https://gaia-converter.com/docs/ds/MGDD21W.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The two specifications referred to in the documentation are ratings for aircraft power systems, often nominally 28 volts.  Your converter will operate normally up to 60 volts.  Then, per the spec, the one-second transient period begins when the input voltage exceeds 60 volts and can be as high as 80 volts throughout the one-second period, but should return to the normal operating input voltage (< 60 volts) by the end of the one-second period.